# Tengo un error de compilación (stray '\361' in programing) traducido perdida '/361' en programacion ¿como se podría solucionar?

Tags: c++

Este es un claro ejemplo de programa en donde practico "composición en c++" con dos clases de nombres FelizcumpleAños y Persona, donde imprime en pantalla un nombre de una persona y su fecha de nacimiento lógicamente sera su fecha de cumple años, pero no me deja compilar el programa debido al problema "Perdida '\361' en el programa", y no se a que se refiere.

```
#include <iostream>                            /*Librería*/
#include <string>                              /*Librería*/

using namespace std;                           /*Permite el uso de "cout, cin"*/

class FelizCumpleAños                          /*clase*/
{
public:
    FelizCumpleAños(int d, int m, int a)       /*constructor*/
    :dia(d), mes(m), anio(a)                   /*Lista de inicialización*/
    {
    }
    void ImprimirDato()                       /*Metodo*/
    {
        cout << dia << "/" << mes << "/" << anio << endl;
    }
private:
    int mes;
    int dia;
    int anio;
};

class Persona                                 /*clase*/
{
public:
    Persona(string n, FelizCumpleAños b)      /*constructor*/
    :nombre(n), bd(b)                         /*Lista de inicializacion*/
    {
    }
    void ImprimirInformacion()                /*Metodo*/
    {
        cout << nombre << endl;
        bd.ImprimirDato();
    }
private:
    string nombre;
    FelizCumpleAños bd;
};

int main()
{
    FelizCumpleAños bd(27, 5, 2000);          /*Instanciamiento de objeto*/
    Persona p("Hernan", bd);                  /*Instanciamiento de objeto*/
    p.ImprimirInformacion();                  /*Seleccion de metodo*/

    return 0;                                 /*Retorno*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

tu problema se debe al nombre de la funcion, Ñ no es un caracter valido para el nombre de tu función.  C++ solo admite, para componer nombres, caracteres alfanumericos del alfabeto inglés (que no tiene acentos ni tildes), dígitos numéricos (salvo el primer carácter) del nombre, y el subrayado _

```
    #include <iostream>                            /*Librería*/
    #include <string>                              /*Librería*/

    using namespace std;                           /*Permite el uso de "cout,     cin"*/

    class FelizCumple                          /*clase*/
    {
      public:
      FelizCumple(int d, int m, int a)       /*constructor*/
      :dia(d), mes(m), anio(a)                   /*Lista de inicialización*/
     {
     }
     void ImprimirDato()                       /*Metodo*/
     {
        cout << dia << "/" << mes << "/" << anio << endl;
      }
    private:
      int mes;
      int dia;
      int anio;
     };

     class Persona                                 /*clase*/
      {
     public:
     Persona(string n, FelizCumple b)      /*constructor*/
    :nombre(n), bd(b)                         /*Lista de inicializacion*/
    {
    }
    void ImprimirInformacion()                /*Metodo*/
    {
        cout << nombre << endl;
        bd.ImprimirDato();
    }
     private:
       string nombre;
       FelizCumple bd;
     };

    int main()
    {
     FelizCumple bd(27, 5, 2000);          /*Instanciamiento de objeto*/
     Persona p("Hernan", bd);                  /*Instanciamiento de objeto*/
     p.ImprimirInformacion();                  /*Seleccion de metodo*/

     return 0;                                 /*Retorno*/
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Como te han señalado, el problema está seguramente en el nombre de tu clase `FelizCumpleAños`, aunque el motivo es otro.

El estándar C++, en el apartado **5.10 Identifiers**, establece que cada `universal-character-name` debe estar en un subconjunto de los caracteres específicados por la norma ISO 10646 (puedes consultarlo en https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard), y la *eñe* (*00F1*) efectivamente está presente entre esos caracteres válidos.

Entonces tu problema no tiene nada que ver con el lenguaje C++, es tu compilador, el IDE o el editor de texto que estás usando.

**Nota**: Si estás usando gcc, hay un viejo bug informado en [UTF-8 support for identifier names in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67224)